# How to show and hide react .tsx file?

Tags: html, reactjs, typescript, hide, show

I have a button. When button is clicked, I want to show table and when click again i want hide data. First data `visible = false`

Jsx file does not recognize state.

The div block name I'm trying to hide is apis.

```
function css() {
 
}

const myfunc= () => {
return (
   
      <div className="btn">
     <button id="veriGoster" onClick={css}> 
       Show
     </button>
         
        </div>
     <div className="apis">
      < Apidata/> // this component import another page.
      </div>

</div>
  )
}
```

Comment: hi where is your state ?

Comment: I cant define state when i write state i see Cannot find name 'state'.ts(2304)

Comment: what ? do you import useState form react ?

Comment: https://imgur.com/xHJXLcR 
I cant use class x extends Component i guess thats way undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you want to do but i try to help you

```
//import of Apidata
import React, { useState } from "react";

const myFunc = () => {
    const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(false);

    const handleHideData = () => {
        setToggle(!toggle);
    };

    return (
        <div className="btn">
            <button id="veriGoster" onClick={handleHideData}>
                Show
            </button>

            {toggle && (
                <div className="apis">
                    <Apidata />
                </div>
            )}
        </div>
    );
};

export default myFunc;
```

Comment: Thank you.  
This is exactly what I wanted